# display category and child id’s separately for masonary filtering

Tags: categories, gwcode-categories

I am using masonry filters to filter entries on a template using category ID’s to differentiate

Filter buttons:

```
    <div class="masonry-filters">
<ul data-option-key="filter">
<li><a class="selected" href="#" data-option-value="*">All</a></li>
   {exp:query sql="
        SELECT *
        FROM exp_categories
        WHERE group_id IN (4)
        ORDER BY cat_name ASC"}
          <li><a href="#" data-option-value=".mansonry-filter-{cat_id} ">{cat_name}</a></li>
        {/exp:query}
</div>
```

Then each entry has the category id in the class for filtering:

```
<article class="masonry-item col-sm-6 col-md-4 mansonry-filter-{categories}{category_id}{/categories} hentry">
```

The problem I have is an entry has a parent AND child category they will not be included in the filter because the ID’s are combined.

ie: USA cat id = 11 New York child id is 65 So this entry’s class will be 1165. I need to separate them so I have just the parent 11 ideally also have 65 as a separate class but not sure how that will work with my filtering.

This would be my goal:

```
class="masonry-item col-sm-6 col-md-4 mansonry-filter-11  mansonry-filter-65 hentry"
```

EDIT: 
I think this is my solution

```
<article class="masonry-item col-sm-6 col-md-4 {exp:gwcode_categories entry_id="{entry_id}" style="linear"} mansonry-filter-{cat_id} {/exp:gwcode_categories} hentry">
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something but aren't you able to accomplish that like this?

```
<article class="masonry-item col-sm-6 col-md-4 {categories}mansonry-filter-{category_id} {/categories} hentry">
```

This would output what you desire. I know nothing about masonry filters.